# vim makefile cerror

Tags: vim

When I type :make inside of vim. it

1) exeutes my makefile

2) parses output for file_name/line_number pairs

3) jumps me to line_number of file_name

4) I move around with :cn and we are happy

This is mostly good. However, when file_name does NOT exist, vim has a tendency to *create* this file, which I do not like. When file_name does NOT exist, I'd like vim to ignore this file_name/line_number pair

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't create the file, but starts a new buffer with that file name.  Maybe you should be worried about the fact that your make output lists a file that doesn't exist.